# Suffix order: -lessness vs -nessless

Tags: suffixes

What is the correct order for combinations of suffixes `-less` and `-ness`?

Are they combined in any order, or is there any rule governing a proper usage?

> hope**lessness**
>   help**lessness**

But:

> weak**nessless**

A side point; not sure if it is related to above. Although the suffixes `-less` makes an adjective while `-ness` makes a noun, it seems that people treat `-nessless` words as nouns:

- [**Eventfulnessless**. Guys, I was serious about my running out of ideas.](http://littlestsun.blogspot.com/2008/05/eventfulnessless.html)
- [Office staff needs work, lack of **timelinessless** than expected follow through listening skills need attention...](http://www.vitals.com/ratings/Dr_Ronnie_Mimran.html)

What am I missing?

Comment: I would say that you're missing the fact that *weaknessless, eventfulnessless, timelinessless* are not real words.

Comment: This is a debated point. There are linguistics papers on this topic, e.g., [Parsing is not weaknessless: suffix ordering revisited](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/stela.manova/workshop_imm13/abstracts/baayen_plag.pdf)  // And the two other examples you give are specious. The first is in someone's blog, and the second is from an illiterate comment about a neurologist.

Comment: @BillFranke I found a 1970 paper that investigates why productive *-less* is blocked on nominalizations ending not only in *-ness*, but also those ending in *-ity* and *-ment*.  You can't have something that is **continuitiless*,  **probabilitiless*, **investmentless*, or **measurementless*, either.

Comment: @tchrist: That's a good find! Have you got a link for it? I don't think that words like "weaknessless" are reasonable, but I'd like to see some linguistic arguments against them beyond their extreme awkwardness. My objections are intuitive and probably primarily stylistic, which aren't good enough, I'm sure.

Comment: @BillFranke [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=7xlZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22happinessless%22&dq=%22happinessless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TyuqULCgM8y8qAGFvYDoDA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA) but they don’t let you see much.

Comment: @tchrist: Thank you for the link. That one sentence makes it worth it.

Comment: I'm not sure that "Eventfulnessless" in your first example is used as a noun; in English we can use many parts of speech as titles.

Comment: ["Should modesty allow us to describe..."](https://youtu.be/W9RodWqY3Js?t=36s) - The Magnetic Fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All existing English words having both *-less* and *-ness* endings are of the *XXXlessness* sort; there are none of the **XXXnessless* variety.

For example:

> affectlessness, agelessness, aimlessness, airlessness, artlessness,
>   awelessness, baselessness, beardlessness, blamelessness, bonelessness,
>   bootlessness, breathlessness, carelessness, causelessness,
>   cheerlessness, childlessness, classlessness, colourlessness,
>   comfortlessness, curelessness, dreamlessness, effortlessness,
>   emotionlessness, endlessness, expressness, factlessness, faithlessness,
>   faultlessness, fearlessness, gracelessness, groundlessness,
>   guiltlessness, haplessness, harmlessness, heartlessness, heedlessness,
>   helplessness, hopelessness, lawlessness, leglessness, lessness,
>   listlessness, mannerlessness, mercilessness, needlessness,
>   nervelessness, noiselessness, normlessness, presciencelessness,
>   recklessness, regardlessness, relentlessness, remedilessness,
>   remorselessness, restlessness, ruthlessness, senselessness,
>   shamelessness, sightlessness, sinlessness, sleeplessness, songlessness,
>   speechlessness, spiritlessness, spotlessness, tastelessness,
>   thanklessness, thoughtlessness, uselessness, voicelessness,
>   warlessness, watchlessness, worthlessness, wretchlessness.

Comment: This was my belief, too, but I failed to find any resources to cite.

Comment: Well what about about [harnessless](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/harnessless)?

Comment: Another example is [witnessless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witnessless). Here *witness* indeed etymologically has the suffix *-ness,* although the meaning has now drifted away from the original, so that this isn't apparent to English speakers.

Comment: @bytebuster Well, there’s something about it [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=7xlZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22happinessless%22&dq=%22happinessless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TyuqULCgM8y8qAGFvYDoDA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA), but I can’t read more of the paper.

Comment: @PeterShor -- how far can this be recursed?  Can a case be dismissed on the grounds of witnesslessnesss?  If a lawyer never suffers such a dismissal, is he witnesslessnesssless?

Comment: The one counterexample I could find is _businessless_, which yields roughly 120 matches in a Google Books search—and yet the _-less_ form in that case is clearly not attached to the sense of "busy-ness" but to the utterly transformed mercantile idea _business_ ("biznis"). Perhaps the fact that _businessless_ exists at any frequency of use confirms how utterly estranged _business_ is from its origin as a state of being busy. (Weirdly enough, there are also 80 or so Google Books matches for _businessness_, although most (not all) of them appear to be typos for _businesses_.)

Answer (score 7):

#### TL;DR: There is no possible ordering of these two suffixes at all.

They are in complementary distribution and cannot be ordered in any way.

---

### What are *-ness* and *-less*

What you fail to realise is that the two suffixes are not added as a group to a single word (despite what dictionaries may tell you): they are both addable, individually, to various types of words.

- *-ness* forms abstract nouns from adjectives (occasionally also from nouns or noun phrases—like *wilderness*, which is historically from **wild deer-ness*—though this is not productive<sup>1</sup>).
- *-less* forms adjectives from nouns and sometimes verbs (*tireless*, for example—also not really productive).

As you can see, this makes for rather a reciprocal definition: *-ness* takes adjectives and makes them nouns; *-less* takes nouns and makes them adjectives.

In other words:

- If you take a base noun (say, *spot*) and add *-less*, you create a new word: a derived adjective, *spotless*. Add *-ness* to that, and you create another new word: a derived noun, *spotlessness*.
- If you take a base adjective (say, *kind*) and add *-ness*, you create a derived noun, *kindness*. Add *-less* to that, and you create a derived adjective, *kindnessless*.

### Recursion

In both these cases, you could theoretically continue the cycle ad nauseam, or at least until you no longer have the faintest idea what what you’re saying is supposed to mean (is something that is *spotlessnesslessnesslessnessless* clean or dirty? Heaven knows!). This process is part of what is known as *recursion*: applying a process to an input that is itself the result of the process you’re applying.

Continuing the cycle more than once or twice is highly impractical, obviously, but it does plays perfectly by the rules of English morphology, and the main reason it’s not practically usable is that English speakers cannot keep that level of abstraction and repeated negation in their heads. That’s a semantic constraint, a limitation in the part of our brains that attach logical meaning to the words we hear, once they’ve been parsed.

The only **morphological** limitation to using these suffixes productively is that *-ness* must be added to adjectives and *-less* to nouns. As such, there is no possible order between the two: they cannot appear in the same place, which rules out any internal ordering of them, as ‘ordering’ implies structurally parallel elements. In *spotlessness*, it is not the case that both *-less* and *-ness* equally and simultaneously modify *spot*; rather, *-less* modifies *spot*, while *-ness* modifies not *spot*, but *spotless*.

#### Testing

The simplest way to verify that this is so is simply to take some of the words combining both suffixes and reverse the suffixes. You will find very quickly that this is not possible *in either direction*. If there were any kind of internal ordering rule going on here, you would expect that one order always won out, which is not the case:

> ***-lessness* => *-nessless*** (base word is a noun)
>   hopelessness => *hopenessless
>   helplessness => *helpnessless
>
> ***-nessless* => *-lessness*** (base word is an adjective)
>   weaknessless => *weaklessness
>   timelinessless => *timelilessness<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I’m ignoring here the humorous broadening of *-ness* to be used with just about any noun. Things like *houseness* or *foreheadness* do exist and are used, but they’re a different kettle of fish not directly related to this question.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> The root word here is of course *time*, which is a noun; but the derivational base to which *-ness* is added is *timely*, which is a derived adjective just like *timeless* would be. (*-ly* is most commonly used to derive adverbs from adjectives, but it can also be used to derive adjectives from a variety of sources: *timely*, *comely*, *gainly*, etc.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The -ness suffix makes an abstract noun out of a word.  The -less suffix means being without something.  So [root]-less-ness is the abstract condition of being without the root.  [root]-ness-less is being without the abstract condition based on the root.

Comment: It took me a while to parse this, and I'm guessing whoever downvoted just found this answer too difficult to understand (or difficult enough not to be useful). I will say that I get and agree with the gist of this (ultimately, it says what I would have said if I bothered to answer this question), but I think it would be more effective and accessible if it used real examples (such as *weaknessless* in the OP's question).

Comment: Well, my answer does contradict the accepted answer that the -nessless ending is "impossible," but personally I found neither that contention nor the cited source to be convincing, especially given the counterexamples people found.