# What's the difference between un- adjectives and -less adjectives?

Tags: synonyms

What's the difference, if any, between

- talentless and untalented
- luckless and unlucky
- dauntless and undaunted
- hapless and unhappy, etc.?

Can the answer to this be generalized, i.e. is it always the same kind or shade of difference, or does the difference differ in each individual pair?

Comment: Off the top of my head, ***-less*** normally attaches to *nouns*, but ***un-*** primarily attaches to *adjectives/adverbs*. So you're ***carless*** if you don't have a car, but there's no such thing as an ***uncar*** (and even if you're very unlucky indeed, you can't have ***unluck*** either). In the case of *hapless, unhappy* the former denies the presence of ***hap*** (noun; *good fortune*) where the latter negates the state of being ***happy*** (adjective; joyous).

Answer (score 6):

According to Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (2002), *-less* words fall into two main categories: words where the *-less* form indicates simply "without" (as, for example, *bottomless*, *childless*, *defenceless*, and *lawless*), and words where the *-less* form "indicate[s] something that is unaffected by the action of the verb, or some failure or inability to carry out that action" (as, for example, *dauntless*, *quenchless*, *relentless*, *tireless*).

In contrast, Quinion says, the prefix *un-* usually lends the simple meaning "not" to the resulting word; but in some instances it "often has a stronger and less neutral force than just negation (so it is not equivalent to NON-): ***unkind*** can mean active cruelty rather than simple lack of kindness; to say someone is ***un-American*** can imply an active antagonism to American ways. Furthermore, with verbs, Quinion says, *un-* "usually has the sense of reversing some state" (as, for example, *unburden*, *unlock*, *unsettle*, *untie*).

So on a basic level, the split between *-less* words and *un-* words is the difference between "without" and "not." But in addition, Quinion suggests, some *-less* words imply a resistance to an embedded verb, and some *un-* words either express a reversal of an embedded verb or go beyond mere negation to suggest an active opposition to an embedded adjective.

Answer (score 5):

In the original examples listed, there is not only a difference in the prefixes, but also the suffixes. This goes along with [FumbleFingers' comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300050/whats-the-difference-between-un-adjectives-and-less-adjectives#comment675361_300050) that "*-less* normally attaches to nouns, but *un-* primarily attaches to adjectives/adverbs." And to further complicate the matter, *un-* can also attach to verbs (usually with a slightly different meaning), and there are some adjectives that derive from participles of these verbs, so we get contrasts words like *undone* that can have two distinct meanings ("never done" or "once done, now reversed").

This is relevant because usually, you can't actually attach these affixes to the same stem; three of your examples use a noun X and a related but not identical adjective Y as the stems for the pair of words. (The exception is *dauntless* and *undaunted*, which the dictionaries that I have consulted say are both from the verb *to daunt*). Differences in meaning may already exist at this stage (*talent* n. vs. *talented* adj., *luck* n. vs. *lucky* adj., *hap* n. vs. *happy* adj.).

As others have mentioned, *X-less* can be approximately glossed as "without X," and *un-Y* can be approximately glossed as "not Y."

So in this answer, I'm going to discuss how the suffixes used may affect the meaning, and how generalizable the meaning of the suffixes is. I'm sorry if this is somewhat tangential to your original question; however, I thought I'd mention it since I don't see it discussed in any of the other answers.

- luckless and unlucky

In this case, we have the suffix *-y* used to form an adjective meaning "characterized by (having) X" from an noun X. Adding the prefix "un-" to this adjective would according to my gloss result in the overall meaning *unlucky* = "not characterized by (having) luck"; in this case, the scope of the negation in actual usage is always narrower "characterized by not having luck." (Sven Yarg's answer describes this better.)

- hapless and unhappy

Here we also have the same suffix *-y*. But, the meaning of the adjective *happy* has actually evolved further than the original noun. It is not accurate to define it as "characterized by (having) hap." The word [*hap*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hap) (which is now archaic) had a primary meaning of "good luck" or "prosperity." While the adjective *happy* can still sometimes mean *fortunate* (applied to an event or a person), it is often used to mean simply that someone is pleased or contented.

This difference in meaning is reflected in the derived words [*hapless*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hapless) (which Merriam Webster defines as "having no luck : very unfortunate") and [*unhappy*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unhappy) (according to Merriam Webster, "sad, depressed, or disappointed : not happy").

*Happiness* is a related noun that is more equivalent in meaning to *happy* (because it is derived from the adjective). And "without happiness" seems pretty much a synonym to "unhappy." But, there is no such word as **happinessless* (this is part of a more general trend where [we generally can't apply the suffix *-less* to nouns ending in *-ness*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91663/suffix-order-lessness-vs-nessless)).

Answer (score 2):

*-less* generally means without, lacking in, or an inability to do; *un-* typically means not, or the reversal or opposite of some state. However, in the common vernacular, I think the distinction only applies on a case-by-case basis. For example, 'unlimited' and 'limitless' both mean *sans* limits, however 'stainless' and 'unstained' have come to mean two different things (the first implies that it does not stain ever, whereas unstained suggests that something has yet to be stained.)

Comment: But does "unless" mean lacking in uns, or not less?

Comment: @Hot Licks There endeth the first lessun.

Comment: Excellent observation. My hat's off to you. :)

Comment: feckless, joyless,restless -- where are the *un-'s*?

Comment: I always *knew* it was a mistake for Thatcher to close the fecking mines! How are we supposed to deal with our feckless youth when the stockpiles of feck run out?

Comment: @deadrat - Well, there is unrest, some of it here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - What the feck are you talking about?